# How to add current active states in pagination bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

How to add current active states in pagination bootstrap?

my code

```
...
<?php for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>
     <li class="page-item">
        <a href='<?php echo "?page=$page"; ?>' class="links"><?php  echo $page; ?></a>
     </li>
<?php endfor; ?> 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `active` to `li`.

Example

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.pagination a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.pagination a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
</script>
```