# How to add Last Page Link to the Pagination

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

How to add Last Page Link to the Pagination bootstrap, im searching in the internet but no one success.

my code for pagi

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="archives.php" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>
      <li class="page-item active">

    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
    <a href='<?php echo "?page=$page"; ?>' class="links"><?php  echo $page; ?></a>
 </li>
    <?php endfor; ?> 
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

for the first page im just need to add `/archives.php`

Comment: Seems to be an additional/edited version of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794888/how-to-add-current-active-states-in-pagination-bootstrap

Comment: they said, dont ask more then 1 question in 1 link, that why im create 1 more question